# How do I accumulate code coverage with ctest and gtest_discover_tests?

Tags: unit-testing, code-coverage, googletest, ctest

I am using ctest with test_discover_tests to unit test my applications.  It appears that ctest calls my test executable for each individual test (see below for an example).  I believe this results in the default.profraw code coverage file being overwritten for each test, so I only get code coverage for the last test that was executed.

As an example:
ctest --verbose -R Test1|Test2

57: Test command: /home/user/project_dir/build_unit_test/project/project_test "--gtest_filter=TestUnit.Test1" "--gtest_also_run_disabled_tests"

57: Test timeout computed to be: 10000000

57: Running main() from gtest_main.cc

57: Note: Google Test filter = TestUnit.Test1

57: [==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.

57: [----------] Global test environment set-up.

57: [----------] 1 test from TestUnit

57: [ RUN      ] TestUnit.Test1

57: [       OK ] TestUnit.Test1 (6 ms)

57: [----------] 1 test from TestUnit (6 ms total)

57:

57: [----------] Global test environment tear-down

57: [==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (6 ms total)

57: [  PASSED  ] 1 test.

9/10 Test #57: project.TestUnit.Test1 ..............   Passed    0.05 sec

test 58

```
  Start 58: project.TestUnit.Test2
```

58: Test command: /home/user/project_dir/build_unit_test/project/project_test "--gtest_filter=TestUnit.Test2" "--gtest_also_run_disabled_tests"

58: Test timeout computed to be: 10000000

58: Running main() from gtest_main.cc

58: Note: Google Test filter = TestUnit.Test2

58: [==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.

58: [----------] Global test environment set-up.

58: [----------] 1 test from TestUnit

58: [ RUN      ] TestUnit.Test2

58: [       OK ] TestUnit.Test2 (1 ms)

58: [----------] 1 test from TestUnit (1 ms total)

58:

58: [----------] Global test environment tear-down

58: [==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (2 ms total)

58: [  PASSED  ] 1 test.
10/10 Test #58: project.TestUnit.Test2 ..............   Passed    0.04 sec